# Is there a convention or guideline for mutable state in a Blazor component?

Tags: razor, blazor

Coming from *React JS*, I wonder if Blazor has the concepts of State and Property. See the code below:

```
<div>@field</div>
<button @onclick=@(() => field = Random.Shared.Next())>Change field</button>

<div>@Prop</div>
<button @onclick=@(() => Prop = Random.Shared.Next())>Change prop</button>

@code {
    private int field;

    [Parameter]
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}
```

There is absolutely no difference between `field` and `Prop`, except that you can set `Prop` from the parent's template. I haven't been able to create a property that cannot be updated within the component, since the public setter is required.

It seems to be up to the team to decide whether it makes sense to update a property within the component or not.

Is there a convention/best practice/guideline about that?

Comment: Seems like a fun way to test async race conditions.  1, 2, 3. . . GO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a convention/best practice/guideline about that?

Yes: do no do that.

Most 'official' is in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#overwritten-parameters):

> Our general guidance is not to create components that directly write to their own parameters after the component is rendered for the first time.

and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bind-across-more-than-two-components):

> Generally, avoid creating components that write directly to their own component parameters. ...

but that is repeated and explained in many places.

Comment: Good to know that there is no way to enforce it, at the moment. I would have wasted my time trying.